# Characters used to specify low/standard/medium/high quality/definition in video sharing websites

Tags: translation, websites

I wonder what are the most common characters used in video sharing websites to specify options for the vide reproduction quality, in particular for [this one](http://www.tudou.com).

Comment: Not sure whether this is what you asked. 超清(Super High Quality)/高清(High Quality)/流畅(Standard)?

Comment: @CaffHuang Thanks, I think that what you posted plus the answer below are all I wanted to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For streaming video, it is common to say:

- 低清 (under 480p = 480 horizontal lines)
- 標清 (DVD resolution: 480p/576p)
- 高清 (720p or above)

Downloadable videos are sometimes marked as "超高清", which may mean 1080p (or even 4K), or simply a high bitrate 720p encode having excellent quality.